# QTextCursor, QTextTable and default left margin

Tags: qt

I am generated a qtextdocument in order to print it. In my document I insert a QTextTable.

My problem is that the table has a left margin by default and I do not find how to delete it.

Example of result:

```
Some text
     table row 1
     table row 2
```

The result I need:

```
Some text
table row 1
table row 2
```

My code:

```
QTextDocument textDocument;
QTextCursor cursor(&textDocument);


cursor.insertText("Some text");

QTextTableFormat tableFormat;
tableFormat.setCellPadding(5);
tableFormat.setHeaderRowCount(2);
tableFormat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
tableFormat.setTopMargin(10);
tableFormat.setPadding(0);
tableFormat.setBorderStyle(QTextFrameFormat::BorderStyle_Solid);
tableFormat.setBorderBrush(QBrush(Qt::black, Qt::SolidPattern));
tableFormat.setWidth(QTextLength(QTextLength::PercentageLength, 100));
tableFormat.setCellSpacing(0);
tableFormat.setLeftMargin(0);
QTextTable *table = cursor.insertTable(2, 11, tableFormat);
```

If you can help me, Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line needs to change:

```
tableFormat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
```

to

```
tableFormat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
```

or just leave the `setAlignment` out completely.

That or the width of the table needs to get set to 100% of the container it is in.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, 

I am already using :

tableFormat.setWidth(QTextLength(QTextLength::PercentageLength, 100));

to set the width 100% but removing AlignCenter fix the problem, it s a bit like if AlignCenter add a left margin and move the table to the right.

Thank you for your